# Issue with Tkinter and destroy

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a Tkinter GUI I created and want to add threading at some point and set up a class for the GUI. When I add the class everything works as it did before but I have a button the closes the program (root.destroy()) Here is an example of what is happening.

This is what I am starting with:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from Tkinter import *
import serial
import time

aSND = '/dev/ttyACM0' #Sets  arduino board to something easy to type
baud = 9600 #Sets the baud rate to 9600
ser = serial.Serial(aSND, baud) #Sets the serial connection to the Arduino board and sets the baud rate as "ser"


def end():
    ser.write('d')
    time.sleep(1.5)
    root.destroy()

root = Tk()
root.geometry('800x480+1+1')
root.title('Root')
buttona = Button(root, text='End Program', command=end)
buttona.place(x=300, y=75)

root.mainloop()
```

If I change the program to include a class then I get this error message:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1437, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/pi/projects/examplegui.py", line 32, in end
    LCARS.destroy()
NameError: global name 'root' is not defined
```

Here is the same program with the class added:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from Tkinter import *
import serial
import time

aSND = '/dev/ttyACM0' #Sets the arduino board to something easy to type
baud = 9600 #Sets the baud rate to 9600
ser = serial.Serial(aSND, baud) #Sets the serial connection to the Arduino board and sets the baud rate as "ser"

class program1():

    def end():
        ser.write('d')
        time.sleep(1.5)
        root.destroy()

    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('800x480+1+1')
    root.title('Root')
    buttona = Button(root, text='End Program', command=end)
    buttona.place(x=300, y=75)

program1.root.mainloop()
```

Thank you,

Robert

Answer (score 0):

Your class has a poor design.

Here is a simplified, working solution:

```
from Tkinter import *


class Program1(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry('800x480+1+1')
        self.root.title('Root')
        self.buttona = Button(self.root, text='End Program', command=self.end)
        self.buttona.place(x=300, y=75)

    def end(self):
        self.root.destroy()

Program1().root.mainloop()
```